# Displaying self-referencing table's data in a c# application

Tags: c#, ado.net

I have following table:

```
---------------------
Id    Title   Parent
---------------------
1     Parent    NULL
2     Level_1    1
3     Level_2    1
4     Level_3    1
5     Level     NULL
6     Level_New  5
```

Now I want to display these data in my console application, I know I need a recursive function but no idea how to do it becuase I want to read these data using ADO.NET not EntityFramework.In EF I could define a model that has a navigation property for children:

```
public class Menu
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Menu> Children { get; set; }
}
```

But the problem is that I don't want to use EF. I want to do it using raw ADO.NET

Comment: Use Self Join query

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: @NiyokoYuliawan SQL SERVER

Answer (score 0):

Recursion isn't fun, this is a solution that I used to test for a much larger recursion

```
public class MyObject
{

    public string Id;
    public string ParentId;
    public string Name;
    public string Comments;

}
```

a lot of this code you wont need, but this should give you want you need on recursion.

```
 private void BindTree(IEnumerable<MyObject> list, TreeNode parentNode, string previousNode)
        {
            var myObjects = list as IList<MyObject> ?? list.ToList();
            var nodes = myObjects.Where(x => (parentNode == null ? x.ParentId == "[].[].[(root)]" : x.ParentId == parentNode.Value));

            var listOfNodeNames = new List<string>();

            foreach (var node in nodes)
            {


                var newNode = new TreeNode(node.Name, node.Id);



                BindTree(myObjects, newNode, previousNode);
            }

        }
```

The above code does the recursion I need ( code you wont need stripped out ) and builds a treeview on a page based on data from a datatable.

But, this should give you want you need to do your recursion.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pull data from server first, then construct tree on client side. Beware of circular reference.

First, change your `Menu` class to ensure that `Children` will never `null`

```
public class Menu
{
    public Menu()
    {
        Children = new HashSet<Menu>();
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? Parent { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Menu> Children { get; private set; }
}
```

Then pull the data from database, and construct the tree

```
var connBuilder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder();
connBuilder.DataSource = "localhost";
connBuilder.InitialCatalog = "YourDatabaseName";
connBuilder.IntegratedSecurity = true;

using (var con = new SqlConnection(connBuilder.ToString()))
{
    con.Open();

    var list = new List<Menu>();                
    //pull data from database               
    using (var cmd = con.CreateCommand())
    {
        cmd.CommandText = "SELECT Id, Title, Parent FROM [dbo].[YourTableName]";
        using (var reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                list.Add(new Menu
                {
                    Id = reader.GetInt32(0),
                    Title = reader.GetString(1),
                    Parent = reader.IsDBNull(2) ?(int?) null : reader.GetInt32(2)
                });
            }
        }
    }

    //construct tree
    var newList = new List<Menu>();
    foreach (var l1 in list)
    {
        if (l1.Parent == null)
        {
            newList.Add(l1);
        }

        foreach (var l2 in list)
        {
            if (l2.Parent == l1.Id)
            {
                l1.Children.Add(l2);
            }
        }
    }

    // do whatever you want with newList
}
```

You will get data like this

[image]